# Why won't the concatenation operator work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the test code:

```
var current_page= 0;
$('#background_music').append('<img id="bm'+current_page+'" src="success.png"   width="68px" height= "68px"/>');
$("#"+ "bm'+current_page+'").offset({top: 171, left: 41});
```

In this example, it doesn't work since the image won't give the expected offset. 
What's wrong with this:

```
"bm'+current_page+'"
```

However, if I change this to

```
$("#"+ "bm"+current_page).offset({top: 171, left: 41});
```

It works.

1. What is the difference?
2. Doesn't the code `" bm'+current_page+' "` generate a string: `"bm0"`?

Update:
1. What's the difference? I just can't figure it out this **+variable+**. In my past question, I have posted such a similar one. However, I didn't figure it out after all...

Comment: Shouldn't it be "bm'"+current_page+"'" ??

Comment: To answer question 2): no, obviously. You wouldn't be asking if it did.

Comment: @Guffa   How about " "bm" + '+current_page+' "? Would it generate bm0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
$("#bm" + current_page)
```

instead of

```
$("#"+ "bm'+current_page+'")
```

---

The following is just one string:

```
"bm'+current_page+'"
```

The string delimiter here `"` (double quote), so nested single quotes (`'`) here are just nothing else than characters. The string ends by the last `"`.

However, In

```
'<img id="bm' + current_page + '" src="success.png" width="68px" height="68px"/>'
```

the string delimiter is `'` (single quote) which means that nested double quotes (`"`) are mere characters ending up in a concatenation of two strings.

Comment: But img id="bm'+current_page+'" causes  id= "bm0"~

Comment: @Stallman you're confused by the nested quotes in the construction of the `<img>` tag.

Comment: So the double quote "" here : id="bm'+current_page+'" is not a string delimiter? Then what does the operation of id="bm'+current_page+'" actually do?

Comment: Oh, I'm also editing, sorry. Does the variable current_page=0 or current_page="0" will affect the concatenation?

Comment: @Stallman, it won't. You need to think about the string as it is but from where you copied from! [Read a bit about it](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html)

Comment: Ok. It means I can generate a string by writing this:
 "one_string '+ a_variable +'"
and it equals to: one_string + the content of a_variable, and generating the same string. Is it?

Comment: @Stallman, no, it generates `one_string '{a_variable}'`. Single quote in a double quoted string is just a single quote

Comment: But why id= "bm' + current_page + '" generate a string bm0

Comment: Oh my god, because as I said you need to look at the **WHOLE** string not only a small part of it. It's irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

@Stallman this should help you understand how quotations work http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html

Answer (score 0):

It's this line that is wonky:

```
$("#"+ "bm'+current_page+'").offset({top: 171, left: 41});
```

Try the following, we're fixing the mixed up quotes.

```
$('#bm'+current_page).offset({top: 171, left: 41});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#"+ "bm'+current_page+'").offset({top: 171, left: 41});
```

I think the problem lies in this line. I think it should be:

```
$("#bm" + current_page).offset({top: 171, left: 41});
```